# CSS Hide Text But Show Image?

Tags: html, css

I need to change something without touching HTML codes.

So I have this code in my HTML

```
<span class="share"> 
    <ul>
        <li>Share &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
        <li class="twitter"><a href="#">twitter</a></li>
        <li class="facebook"><a href="#">facebook</a></li>
        <li class="delicious"><a href="#">delicious</a></li>
        <li class="friendfeed"><a href="#">friendfeed</a></li>
        <li class="addthis"><a href="#">share</a></li>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </ul>
</span>
```

and this in CSS

```
.twitter {
    background: url('../images/tt.png') no-repeat; 
    width:      10px; 
    height:     14px;
}
```

This works fine, but twitter text is visible under the twitter logo, I don't want those texts to appear in my list, I want to replace them with images in CSS.

Is it possible to do without touching HTML Codes?

Comment: Here: https://jsfiddle.net/hetr1whg/

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Make the text transparent.  Since it's a link, you'll want to use a few selectors to make sure all cases are addressed:

```
.twitter a, .twitter a:link, .twitter a:visited
{
    color: transparent;
}
```

**Edit:** This other option, while more verbose, has the benefit of keeping the focus border (the little dots that appear when a link is selected) to the size and shape of the twitter icon.  Also, the text will not be revealed if selected and copied and pasted.  It becomes invisible and unselectable.  Here is the technique:

```
.twitter a {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 0;
    height: 14px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: The text is selectable and widths do vary, i got like 5 social bookmarking links next to each other, i want their paddings to be equal.

Comment: @Tumay - Funny, my edit came in one second after your comment and seems to address your comment perfectly.  :)

Answer (score 11):

You could use `text-indent`:

```
text-indent: -9999px; /* get rid of any text */
```

Comment: That moves the link too.  The twitter icon becomes unclickable.

Comment: this works fine when display is block, inline-block o similar

Answer (score 8):

Try making your `font-size : 0px;` in your css.

Answer (score 5):

use text-indent with a little magic in it :)

HTML:

```
           <span class="share"> 
                <ul>
                    <li>Share &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                    <li class="twitter"><a href="#" class="twitter">twitter</a></li>
                    <li class="facebook"><a href="#">facebook</a></li>
                    <li class="delicious"><a href="#">delicious</a></li>
                    <li class="friendfeed"><a href="#">friendfeed</a></li>
                    <li class="addthis"><a href="#">share</a></li>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </ul>
            </span>
```

CSS:

> ```
> a.twitter {
>     background-image:url('../images/tt.png');
>     display:block;
>     height:58px;
>     text-indent:-9999px;
>     width:200px;
> }
> ```

So you see the text is indented but still the image is still clickable because i've put a class in the twitter link ;)

Comment: OP specifically states they cannot alter the HTML.