# Displaying Multiple Image Links instead of Text in WebGrid?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webgrid, html.actionlink, url.action, mvchtmlstring

I have a WebGrid definition and three links in a single column by using **Html.ActionLink**. But, when I do not use "LinkText" property, the **applicantId** property is passed as **null** value to the Controller.

On the other hand, when just using LinkTexts instead of " ", the id parameters can be passed successfully (Types as "My Link Text" below). However, I do not want to display text on the link and I just wanted to display Image.

I think there might be a typing mistake or there would be another ways suitable for MVC4 Razor like **@Url.Action**, etc. Here is my code in Razor View.

Could you help me please?

Thanks in advance.

**View:**

```
//for using multiple Html.ActionLink in a column using Webgrid
grid.Column("Operations", format: (item) =>
 new HtmlString(
       Html.ActionLink("My Link Text", "Edit", "Admin", new
       {
           applicantId = item.ApplicantID,               
           title = "Detail",
           @class = "icon-link",
           style = "background-image: url('../../Content/icons/detail.png')"
       }, null).ToString() +
       Html.ActionLink(" ", "Edit", "Admin", new
       {
           applicantId = item.ApplicantID, 
           title = "Edit",
           @class = "icon-link",
           style = "background-image: url('../../Content/icons/edit.png')"
       }, null).ToString() +
       Html.ActionLink(" ", "Edit", "Admin", new
       {
           applicantId = item.ApplicantID,
           title = "Delete",
           @class = "icon-link",
           style = "background-image: url('../../Content/icons/delete.png')"
       }, null).ToString()
 )
)



<style type="text/css">
    a.icon-link {
        background-color: transparent; 
        background-repeat: no-repeat; 
        background-position: 0px 0px;
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer; 
        width: 16px;
        height: 16px;
        margin-right: 8px; 
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Are you using the same Edit Action for Display, Edit, and Delete functions, or you just forgot to change the Action name in your `Html.ActionLink`s?

Comment: Also, it seems like you did not explain the problem correctly. The id is null when you do not use a link text or when you do use it?

Comment: When I do not use linktext, applicantId property returns null value. I simply want to use three image link (without text) instead of text link inside HtmlString() in one coulumn above. Thanks.

Comment: The answer provided below is good, but you don't have to do that. You can just assign css classes to your links, and give them background images in your stylesheet.

Comment: Similar method had already been in the question, but it does not seem to be working good (at least without "title" property at here"). So, as far as I see, for multiple item into one column in WebGrid, this approach maybe a need. However, if you could give an example as you described and change the code above according to your example maybe @H.Johnson apply it and inform us if it works properly.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have tried your answer and saw that it does not make any sense regarding to the result. On the other hand, regarding to the Delete method, if [HttpPost] is removed it should work. 
@H.Johnson: Could you please also check answer and this opt?

Comment: @MuratYILDIZ: Yes, by removing the [HttpPost], the id field can be passed without any problem and I think I can use Delete method like that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use custom HTML Helper method in order to use it easily. To do this:

1. Create a folder called HtmlHelpers and create a class named MyHelpers in this folder. Then define your class like below (you might improve it by adding some extra properties).

**MyHelpers.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace <YourProjectName>.WebUI.HtmlHelpers
{
    public static class MyHelpers
    {            
        public static MvcHtmlString ImageLink(this HtmlHelper html, string imagePath, string alt, string cssClass,
           string action, string controllerName)
        {
            return ActionImage(html, imagePath, alt, cssClass, action, controllerName, null);
        }

        public static MvcHtmlString ImageLink(this HtmlHelper html, string imagePath, string alt, string cssClass,
           string action, string controllerName, object routeValues)
        {
            var currentUrl = new UrlHelper(html.ViewContext.RequestContext);
            var imgTagBuilder = new TagBuilder("img"); // build the <img> tag
            imgTagBuilder.MergeAttribute("src", currentUrl.Content(imagePath));
            imgTagBuilder.MergeAttribute("title", alt);
            imgTagBuilder.MergeAttribute("class", cssClass);
            string imgHtml = imgTagBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing);
            var anchorTagBuilder = new TagBuilder("a"); // build the <a> tag
            anchorTagBuilder.MergeAttribute("href", currentUrl.Action(action, controllerName, routeValues));
            anchorTagBuilder.InnerHtml = imgHtml; // include the <img> tag inside
            string anchorHtml = anchorTagBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);
            return MvcHtmlString.Create(anchorHtml);
        }
    }
}
```

2. Rebuild your project and then add this line to your Razor View:

   @using .WebUI.HtmlHelpers
3. Then use this Html Helper method in your View like this:

   @Html.ImageLink("../../Content/icons/delete.png", "Delete", "your-class", "Delete", "Admin", new { item.ApplicantID })

Smilarly, if you want to use multi image link in the same column you can merge html strings like that:

**View:**

```
....
grid.Column("Operations", style: "your-class", format: (item) =>
 new HtmlString(
      @Html.ActionImage("../../Content/icons/detail.png", "Detail", "your-class", "Detail", "Admin", new { item.ApplicantID }).ToString() +
      @Html.ActionImage("../../Content/icons/edit.png", "Edit", "your-class", "Edit", "Admin", new { item.ApplicantID }).ToString() +
      @Html.ActionImage("../../Content/icons/delete.png", "Delete", "your-class", "Delete", "Admin", new { item.ApplicantID }).ToString()

 )
)
...
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this wonderful explanations. I could easily place my image link into one column in my WebGrid. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Your Action Links are not being called correctly. You are adding the Html Attributes to your Route Values. Your Action Links should look like this:

```
   Html.ActionLink("My Link Text", "Detail", "Admin", new
   {
       applicantId = item.ApplicantID              
   }, new 
   {            
       title = "Detail",
       @class = "icon-link"
   })
```

Check this link to see how you can hide the link text, and display an image instead using css: [CSS Hide Text But Show Image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976675/css-hide-text-but-show-image)